# Export picturebox image to localdisk

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, gdi+

I want to export the image in the picture box to a location in the HDD, this image is set to the picturebox from an image type column in MSSQL database table.

I have already written the following code to acheive this task. However I get a generic GDI+ error by the try catch code.

> This code exoprts the image in the picturebox to the location specified by save file dialog box.

```
        Dim fileName As String = exportDialog.FileName
        Dim expImage As Image = picBox.BackgroundImage
        Try
            If expImage IsNot Nothing Then
                expImage.Save(fileName)
                MessageBox.Show("File exported successfully")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            __WRITELOG(ex)
        End Try
```

> This is the code that get the image from the database and converts it to be able to display in the picturebox

```
        If Not IsDBNull(img) Then
            Using mStream As New MemoryStream(img, 0, img.Length)
                mStream.Write(img, 0, img.Length)
                __IMAGE_FROM_STREAM = Image.FromStream(mStream, True)
                '//This __IMAGE_FROM_STREAM is set as the image into the picturebox & it works....!
            End Using
        End If
```

[image: Try catch error photo]

I have checked into this problem, but most others have got the GDI+ error when saving file which have been loaded to picturebox from a location in the disk rather than the database. And there solutions were regarding disk locks which doesn't apply to this situation. Any support/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Either copy the image's data directly from the DB to the disk or assign a `.Clone` (a new instance). `picBox.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(mStream).Clone`

Comment: `__IMAGE_FROM_STREAM = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(img), True)`. Don't declare the `MemoryStream` with a `Using` statement. Dispose of the Image before you set another (e.g., `PictureBox1?.Image.Dispose() PictureBox1.Image = [new Image]`). The underlying stream is released when the Image is disposed. When you save the Image, specify the `ImageFormat`.

Comment: @Jimi what is the ? meaning in your code, you have mentioned PictureBox1?.Image.Dispose(). I am not used to ? symbol, am I missing something, is this a valid syntax. Thanks

Comment: Well, that's the Elvis (null-conditional operator). It performs a `null` test before accessing a member. So, if the `PictureBox.Image` object is `null` (`Nothing`), it doesn't try to call `Dispose()` on it. If the Image is `null` (never assigned to or set to `null`), it won't throw an exception. In this case, it's a shortcut to `If PictureBox.Image IsNot Nothing then PictureBox.Image.Dispose()`

Comment: @Jimi thanks for the clarification, it showed up as an error in visual studio code editor as an invalid syntax.

Comment: You probably have an older version of VB.Net. But, IIRC, it was introduced in VB.Net 14.

Comment: @Jimi can you kindly explain or direct me to a explanation link as to why we have to keep an stream open when getting image from database. Since the image is already loaded into the picturebox, why can not we just use the image property from the picture box to save to disk. I quite don't understand the logical reason.

Comment: This requirement is simply determined by the internal functionality. I don't know what you're doing with these Images, I just saw this: `__IMAGE_FROM_STREAM = Image.FromStream(mStream, True)`. Here, you have bytes coming from a database and a Stream is used to bring in those bytes, in a form that is known to the object that will use it. The Stream needs to remain opened for the life-time of the Object. GDI+ locks the Image file on disc, if you load the Image from a file. The MemoryStream has the advantage that it doesn't use critical resources and it's released when the Image is disposed.

Comment: So, you don't actually need to dispose of the MemoryStream. But, of course, you cannot declare it with a `Using` statement, otherwise it will be disposed of right after, causing the Image object to become unusable.

Comment: @Jimi I removed the using statement and it worked.! Now do I have to manually dispose this or will the framework automatically destroy the stream once the form is closed?

Comment: As described, you don't need to worry about the Stream, you need to diposed of the Image object. You do that each time you assign a new Image, to a PictureBox, for example, with `PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()` (or using the long form, it's the same). This way, when the Form closes, the last Image set is also the only one remaining: you can disposed of it or leave it as it is, if (in VB.Net) the PictureBox was created in the Form's Designer. You can also call `PictureBox.Image?.Dispose()` in the Form.FormClosed event (*safety measure*: controls are not actually disposed of when the Form closes)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211605/discussion-between-codegen-and-jimi).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but I think that the issue is that you are disposing the `Stream` that you are creating the `Image` from. It is usually good to use a `Using` statement because it means automatic disposal of the created object but that is undesirable in this case. Keep the `Stream` around and only dispose it when you are done with the `Image` and dispose that too. You could, for instance, create a custom control that inherited `PictureBox` and had a property for a source `Stream` too, allowing you to keep it with the `Image`.

```vb
Imports System.IO

Public Class PictureBoxEx
    Inherits PictureBox

    Private _imageStream As Stream

    Public WriteOnly Property ImageStream As Stream
        Set
            _imageStream = Value
            Image = Image.FromStream(Value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub DisposeImageAndStream()
        Image?.Dispose()
        _imageStream?.Dispose()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: based on how I have broken down the files keeping the stream in memory is bit of a problem. Changing that code could break some other working functionalities.


Therefore is it possible to create a stream from the image in the picture box at the time when the user selects to export the image to disk & then use that stream to save the image to disk.